# Segmentation fault in strcmp() on C

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

My program to compare strings fails with Segmentation Fault after the second input:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<string.h>

int main (void)

{       
    char* input1;
    char* input2;
    printf("type something: ");
    scanf("%s", &input1);

    printf("type something: ");
    scanf("%s", &input2);

    if(strcmp(input1, input2) == 0)
    {
        printf("u type the same thing\n");  
    }
    else
    {
        printf("u not type the same thing\n");
    }

}
```

output:

```
sekai92@sekai92-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/C_CPP$ make compare
clang -Wall -Werror -ggdb     compare.c   -o compare
sekai92@sekai92-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/C_CPP$ ./compare 
type something: hello
type something: hello
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: `char *input1 = (char *)malloc(64 * sizeof(char));`

Comment: This must be some new definition of "works" I wasn't previously aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input` and `input1` are uninitialized pointers. This causes to [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (C language standard term).

You need to allocate meory using `malloc()` or `calloc()`. 
Or simply use local arrays:

```
char input[SIZE]; 
char input1[SIZE];
```